# Scripting: what is the easiest to extract a value in a tag of a XML file?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, python, xml

I want to read a pom.xml ('Project Object Model' of Maven) and extract the version information. Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project 
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
    <name>project-parent</name>
    <version>1.0.74-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sybase.jconnect</groupId>
        <artifactId>jconnect</artifactId>
        <version>6.05-26023</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
        <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>
</project>
```

How can I extract the version '1.0.74-SNAPSHOT' from above?

Would love to be able to do so using simple bash scripting sed or awk. Otherwise a simple python is preferred.

**EDIT**

1. Constraint

   The linux box is in a corporate environment so I can only use tools that are already installed (not that I cannot request utility such as xml2, but I have to go through a lot of red-tape). Some of the solutions are very good (learn a few new tricks already), but they may not be applicable due to the restricted environment
2. updated xml listing

   I added the dependencies tag to the original listing. This will show some hacky solution may not work in this case
3. Distro

   The distro I am using is RHEL4

Comment: Is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004/parsing-xml-using-unix-terminal sufficient?

Comment: Not really. There are a lot of version tag in the xml (e.g. under dependencies tag). I only want '/project/version'

Comment: Which xml-related tools and libraries are available? Are jvm-based soltuions OK?

Comment: So far I can tell xml2, xmlgrep and perl XML module are not present. Most unix command-line utilities are present. The distro is Redhat EL 4.

Comment: (I couldn't add a comment so I have to reply as an answer, overkill somewhat) Some great answers can be found here..... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735548/xslt-document-function-returns-empty-result-on-maven-pom/2737427#2737427

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893585/how-to-parse-xml-in-bash

Answer (score 19, accepted):

xml2 can convert xml to/from line-oriented format:

```
xml2 < pom.xml  | grep /project/version= | sed 's/.*=//'
```

Comment: xml2 can be found at https://github.com/clone/xml2 - it's original website etc have disappeared.

Answer (score 7):

Other way: xmlgrep and XPath:

```
xmlgrep --text_only '/project/version' pom.xml
```

Disadvantage: slow

Comment: command updated to `xml_grep`

Answer (score 6):

Using `python`

```
$ python -c 'from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree; print ElementTree(file="pom.xml").findtext("{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}version")'
1.0.74-SNAPSHOT
```

Using `xmlstarlet`

```
$ xml sel -N x="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" -t -m 'x:project/x:version' -v . pom.xml
1.0.74-SNAPSHOT
```

Using `xmllint`

```
$ echo -e 'setns x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0\ncat /x:project/x:version/text()' | xmllint --shell pom.xml | grep -v /
1.0.74-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: `cat (//x:version)[1]/text()` when using `xmllint` also works!

Answer (score 5):

Clojure way. Requires only jvm with special jar file:

```
java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main -e "(use 'clojure.xml) (->> (java.io.File. \"pom.xml\") (clojure.xml/parse) (:content) (filter #(= (:tag %) :version)) (first) (:content) (first) (println))"
```

Scala way:

```
java -Xbootclasspath/a:scala-library.jar -cp scala-compiler.jar scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner -e 'import scala.xml._; println((XML.load(new java.io.FileInputStream("pom.xml")) match { case <project>{children @ _*}</project> => for (i <- children if (i  match { case <version>{children @ _*}</version> => true; case _ => false;  }))  yield i })(0) match { case <version>{Text(x)}</version> => x })'
```

Groovy way:

```
java -classpath groovy-all.jar groovy.ui.GroovyMain -e 'println (new XmlParser().parse(new File("pom.xml")).value().findAll({ it.name().getLocalPart()=="version" }).first().value().first())'
```

Comment: This is awesome! Great idea!

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternative in Perl

```
$ perl -MXML::Simple -e'print XMLin("pom.xml")->{version}."\n"'
1.0.74-SNAPSHOT
```

It works with the revised/extended example in the questions which has multiple "version" elements at different depths.

Comment: Slow, (although faster than xmlgrep)

Answer (score 3):

[Hacky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/266720) way:

```
perl -e '$_ = join "", <>; m!<project[^>]*>.*\n(?:    |\t)<version[^>]*>\s*([^<]+?)\s*</version>.*</project>!s and print "$1\n"' pom.xml
```

Relies on correct indentation of the required `<version>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it will not return what I want. Please see the updated pom model.

Comment: Returns "1.0.74-SNAPSHOT". Note that I changed the script after reading about multiple `<version>` things.

Comment: Note: this solution is provided "just for fun" and is not intended to be used in actual product. Better use xml2/xmlgrep/XML::Simple solution.

Comment: Thanks! even though it is 'just for fun' but it is probably the 'most suitable' solution by far because it has minimum number of dependencies: It only requires perl ;-)

Comment: What about doing it from Java? Using pom files implies having JVM installed.

Comment: The background is that I am building a SIT (system integration test) script around the existing maven process. Part of it requires  knowing the version of the maven project. I really want to keep it simple and scripting is the way to go.

Comment: There is also python script in other answer (plus my improved version of it). May be check it?

Answer (score 3):

Work out a very clumsy, one-liner solution

```
python -c "from xml.dom.minidom import parse;dom = parse('pom.xml');print [n for n in dom.getElementsByTagName('version') if n.parentNode == dom.childNodes[0]][0].toxml()" | sed -e "s/.*>\(.*\)<.*/\1/g"
```

The sed at the end is very ugly but i was not able to print out the text of the node with mindom alone.

**Update from _Vi**:

Less hacky Python version:

```
python -c "from xml.dom.minidom import parse;dom = parse('pom.xml');print [i.childNodes.item(0).nodeValue for i in dom.firstChild.childNodes if i.nodeName == 'version'].pop()"
```

**Update from me**

Another version:

```
    python -c "from  xml.dom.minidom import parse;dom = parse('pom.xml');print [n.firstChild.data for n in dom.childNodes[0].childNodes if n.firstChild and n.tagName == 'version']"
```

Answer (score 2):

XSLT way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="text"/>

        <xsl:template match="/">
                <xsl:for-each select="*[local-name()='project']">
                    <xsl:for-each select="*[local-name()='version']">
                        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```
xalan -xsl x.xsl -in pom.xml
```

Comment: If xsltproc is on your system, and it probably is as libxslt is on RHEL4, then you can use it and  the above stylesheet to output the tag, i.e. xsltproc x.xsl prom.xsl.

Answer (score 2):

if "There are a lot of version tag in the xml" then you better forget about doing it with "simple tools" and regexps, that won't do.

try this python (no dependencies):

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

dom = parse('pom.xml')
project = dom.getElementsByTagName('project')[0]
for node in project.childNodes:
    if node.nodeType == node.ELEMENT_NODE and node.tagName == 'version':
        print node.firstChild.nodeValue
```

Comment: What exactly does this script do?

Comment: it loads the XML as a DOM structure using Python's minidom implementation: http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html the idea is to grab the <project> tag that is unique and then iterate over its child nodes (direct childs only) to find the tag <version> that we're looking for and not other tags with the same name in other places.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner using sed:

```
sed '/<dependencies>/,/<\/dependencies>/d;/<version>/!d;s/ *<\/\?version> *//g' pom.xml
```

Comment: Relies on absence of parameters in elements and that extra `<version>`s can be only inside dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I know your question says Linux but if you have the need to do this on Windows without the need of any 3rd party tools such that you can put it in a batch file, Powershell can extract any node from the your pom.xml file like so:

```
powershell -Command "& {select-xml //pom:project/pom:properties/pom:mypluginversion -path pom.xml -Namespace  @{pom='http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0'} | foreach {$_.Node.Innerxml}}" > myPluginVersion.txt
```

Comment: Powershell is now open source and runs on Linux and other platforms. We use it for building in preference to bash, cygwin and ming64.

Answer (score 1):

**awk** works fine without using any extra tools.
`cat pod.xml`

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.networks.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>operation-platform</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>tar.xz</packaging>
  <description>POM was created by Sonatype Nexus</description>
</project>
```

simple and legible way to get the value of `<packaging>` tag:

```bsh
cat pod.xml | awk -F'[<>]' '/packaging/{print $3}'
```

Comment: This does appear to work, but beware:
What it does is set the field separator (FS) to the set of characters < and >;  then it finds all lines with the word "packaging" in them and give you the third field.

Answer (score 0):

```
Return_text_val=$(xmllint --xpath "//*[local-name()='$TagElmnt']" $FILE )
```

Here, try this:

```
$TagElmnt - TagName
$FILE - xml file to parse
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n "/<name>project-parent/{n;s/.*>\(.*\)<.*/\1/p;q}" pom.xml
```

The `-n` option avoids printing non-matching lines; first match (`/.../`) is on the line before the one with wanted text; the `n` command skips to next line, where `s` extracts relevant info thru a capturing group (`\(...\)`), and a backreference (`\1`). `p` prints out, `q` quits.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain this?  Thanks.