# How to extract terms from an HTML document

Tags: macos, html, regex, sublime-text-2

I have a HTML document filled with terms that I need to put into a spreadsheet.

They follow this basic pattern:

```
<ul>
     <li class="name"><a href="spot.html">Spot</a></li>
     <li class="type">Dog</li>
     <li class="color">Red</li>
</ul>
<ul>
     <li class="name"><a href="mittens.html">Mittens</a></li>
     <li class="type">Cat</li>
     <li class="color">Brown</li>
</ul>
<ul>
     <li class="name"><a href="squakers.html">Squakers</a></li>
     <li class="type">Little Parrot</li>
     <li class="color">Rainbow</li>
</ul>
```

It's very consistent.

I need to extract the string within the `li.name a` (so, "Spot") but *only* if the `type` is "Dog" or "Parrot", and put them in a spreadsheet.

I've been trying to use Sublime Text's ability to Find with regex, but I'm really struggling, and since regex and HTML usually [don't play nice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), I was wondering if there is a better and easier way to accomplish this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a JavaScript implementation that actually uses the DOM, checks the `type` class and writes the `name` class if the `type` class contains the appropriate word. If more `type`s are necessary, just add them to the `searchfor` variable with a pipe (`|`) separating them.

```
var searchfor = /Dog|Parrot/gi;

var win = window.open();

var lists = document.body.getElementsByTagName("ul");

for (i in lists) {
    var points = lists[i].getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (j in points) {
        if ((" " + points[j].className + " ").indexOf(" " + "type" + " ") > -1) {
            if (points[j].innerHTML.match(searchfor) != null) {
                for (k in points) {
                    if ((" " + points[k].className + " ").indexOf(" " + "name" + " ") > -1) {
                        win.document.writeln(points[k].innerHTML + "<br />");

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tested on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wdR5Y/

The easiest way to use it is to convert it to a bookmarklet with something like this: http://userjs.up.seesaa.net/js/bookmarklet.html

As JavaScript, it's OS independent and supported by most popular web browsers.

To import to a spreadsheet depends on your spreadsheet application, but often copy and paste is enough (a new window is opened with the output).

---

If it were ID, not class, this would have been a fair bit easier... ah well. Credit to a [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3808886/1030702) for getting the element by class name.

Comment: Thanks, Bob! I can't get the bookmarklet to work, but the idea still applies!

Comment: @bookcasey It works for me™ with Firefox, Chrome or Opera with your sample HTML. Just add the bookmarklet as a bookmark, and use it on the page you want to parse. If your sample HTML doesn't match the real one, then I can't guarantee anything (perhaps you can modify it yourself?).

Answer (score 7):

Don't use Regex to parse XML or HTML, use an XML or HTML parser.

Another approach is to convert XML or HTML to text then use grep

See [Application for extracting XML tags from a document](https://superuser.com/q/416082/52492)
See [Is there a native tool for parsing xml files available on RedHat?](https://superuser.com/q/266641/52492)
See [Scripting: what is the easiest to extract a value in a tag of a XML file?](https://superuser.com/q/369996/52492)